# Is infinispan cache usable as a cluster cache of small resource nodes?

Tags: resources, cluster-computing, infinispan

Suppose, I have a lot of nodes with small resources on memory and cpu maybe 5 or maybe 20.
These nodes are not really reliable, they may be switched of by the User.
They all use a database for readonly master data which will be delivered by a kafka topic connected to from each node.
What I want to achieve is to use infinispan as a distributed[replicated] cache above the database used by the nodes, so that at any node at any point on time has the same "view" on the readonly database.
Can I get this working, especially with low resources and if yes, is there any Link to an example for getting expirience?
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get a definite answer here, you need to try it out. I wouldn't call 5 - 20 CPUs small resources; there's not much going on in background when you're not actively reading/writing the cache so there shouldn't be any 'constant' overhead - just JGroups' heartbeat messages and such.

When using off-heap memory, Infinispan can be started with pretty small JVM heaps (24 MB IIRC, just for the POC), so you might be fine. However if you'll replicate the database on every node it's going to occupy some memory.

If the nodes often come and go, it could cause some churn on CPU. In replicated mode leaves won't matter too much, but when a node joins it will be getting all the data (from different nodes).

Comment: Thank you Radim,
so I think it should generally possible. So I have to implement a POC.